# ScispaCy in google colab

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to build  **NER** model of clinical data using **ScispaCy** in **colab**. I have installed packages like this.

````
!pip install spacy
!pip install scispacy
!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.2.4/en_core_sci_md-0.2.4.tar.gz       #pip install <Model URL>```
````

Then I imported both using

```
import scispacy
import spacy
import en_core_sci_md
```

then used following code to display sentences and entities

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_md")
text ="""Myeloid derived suppressor cells (MDSC) are immature myeloid cells with immunosuppressive activity. They accumulate in tumor-bearing mice and humans with different types of cancer, including hepatocellular carcinoma (HCC)""" 
doc = nlp(text)
print(list(doc.sents))
print(doc.ents)
```

I am getting the following error

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_sci_md'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I don't know why this error is coming, I followed all codes from the official GitHub post of ScispaCy. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I am not too late... I believe you are very close to the correct approach.

I will write my answer in steps and you can choose where to stop.

Step 1)

```
#Install en_core_sci_lg package from the website of spacy  (large corpus), but you can also use en_core_sci_md for the medium corpus.
       
!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.2.4/en_core_sci_lg-0.2.4.tar.gz
```

Step 2)

```
# Import the large dataset
import en_core_sci_lg
```

Step 3)

```
# Identify entities
nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load()
doc = nlp(text)
displacy_image = displacy.render(doc, jupyter = True, style = "ent")
```

Step 4)

```
#Print only the entities
print(doc.ents)
```

Step 5)

```
# Save the result 
save_res = [doc.ents]
save_res
```

Step 6)

```
#Save the results to a dataframe
df_save_res = pd.DataFrame(save_res)
df_save_res
```

Step 7)

```
# In case that you want to visualise the dependency parse
  displacy_image = displacy.render(doc, jupyter = True, style = "dep")
```